# Como fazer mais de um select na mesma query?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, query, select

Como consigo fazer mais de um select na mesma query? Tentei da seguinte forma (utilizando o UNION), mas não funcionou:

**BANCO DE DADOS**

**Tabela: cameras_linhas**

```
id_camera_linha | nome_linha_camera
```

**Tabela: fabricantes**

```
id_fabricante | nome_fabricante
```

**Tabela: cameras**

```
id_camera | fabricantes_id_fabricante (chave estrangeira) | cameras_linhas_id_camera_linha (chave estrangeira) | modelo_camera
```

**cameras.php**

```
function listaCameras($conexao) {
    $cameras = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,"(select c.*, f.nome_fabricante as nome_fabricante from cameras as c join fabricantes as f on c.fabricantes_id_fabricante = f.id_fabricante)
    UNION ALL
    (select c.*, cl.nome_linha_camera as nome_linha_camera from cameras as c join cameras_linhas as cl on c.cameras_linhas_id_camera_linha = cl.id_camera_linha)");

    while($camera = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        array_push($cameras, $camera);
    }

    return $cameras;
}
```

index.php

```
 <?php 
     require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/admin/includes/connect.php";
     require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/admin/includes/cameras.php";

    <?php
        $cameras = listaCameras($conexao); //função para listar os produtos (verificar arquivo includes/produtos.php)

    ?>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

    <?php
        foreach($cameras as $camera) {
    ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?= $camera['nome_fabricante'] //mostra o produto?></td>
            <td><?= $camera['nome_linha_camera'] //mostra o produto?></td>
            <td><?= $camera['modelo_camera'] //mostra o produto?></td>
             <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit.php?id_produto=<?=$camera['id_camera']?>">editar</a> <!-- botão editar -->
            <td>
                <form action="delete.php" method="post"> <!-- botão deletar -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_produto" value="<?=$camera['id_camera']?>" />
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

E o resultado é esse:

[image: Ele consegue localizar sempre apenas um dos selects, o outro ele dá erro, se eu inverter a ordem, o erro passa para o outro select]

Alguém consegue dar uma força? Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Se você fizer na sua função `return mysql_fecth_assoc($resultado)` é o suficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `subqueries`.

Veja:

```
select 
    c.*, 
    f.nome_fabricante as nome_fabricante, 
    temp_sql.nome_linha_camera
from 
     (select 
           c.id_camera,
           c1.nome_linha_camera
      from 
           cameras as c 
           join cameras_linhas as cl 
           on c.cameras_linhas_id_camera_linha = cl.id_camera_linha
      ) temp_sql 
      join cameras as c 
      on temp_sql.id_camera = c.id_camera
      join fabricantes as f 
      on c.fabricantes_id_fabricante = f.id_fabricante
```

Dessa forma, se você quiser acessar a coluna `cl.nome_linha_camera as nome_linha_camera`, você deve fazer `c_linha.nome_linha_camera`.

---

### Veja também

[Subqueries: Onde e quando utilizar](http://www.devmedia.com.br/t-sql-subqueries-onde-e-quando-utilizar/32072)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Fiz a alteração que você sugeriu e retornou o seguinte erro: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\admin\includes\cameras.php on line 38

Linha 38: while($camera = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
array_push($cameras, $camera);
    }

    return $cameras;
}

Comment: Entendi. Você chegou a rodar a query direto no banco? Funciona?

Comment: Rodei, ele deu o seguinte erro: **#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

Comment: Tire o `c.*` da subquery (bem como a vírgula depois dele). Deixe apenas a coluna `cl.nome_linha_camera as nome_linha_camera` na subquery. Tente agora, por favor.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo retorno. Tirei a **c.*,** da subquery e retornou o seguinte erro: **#1242 - Subconsulta retorna mais que 1 registro**

Comment: Eu acrescentei na pergunta a estrutura das tabelas do banco de dados, não sei se isso ajuda na resolução do problema. Estou desde quinta-feira quebrando a cabeça e não consigo resolver esse problema que é "simples".

Comment: Alterei o código do post. Tente rodar agora, por favor. Vai faltar exibir uma coluna.

Comment: Alterei novamente. Agora vai funcionar 100% (eu acho rsrs).

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado. Apenas um detalhe ao invés de c1.nome_linha_camera é cl.nome_linha_camera. VALEU!

Comment: Hehe, blz! Fico feliz por ter ajudado! Pode marcar minha resposta como solução, por favor? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Tente utilizar subquerys e / ou joins caso seja tabelas relacionais, e não esqueça de filtrar tudo pelo group by caso tenha dados replicados, mas atente-se a estrutura da sua base de dados, pois caso venha crescer a manutenção do seu sistema ficará dificil.